# Single phase motor does not stop

Tags: motor, motor-controller, triac, speed

I have a circuit that controls sine phase motor with three triacs.
When I turn it on it works properly, I can regulate the speed, but when I turn it off the motor does not stop, it still spins but not so fast. When I plug controller out the rotor stops. I found out that after turning off the capacitor in motor has still like 120 V (in my country we have 230 V AC).

I thought that maybe it is a problem with gate signal that does not disappear after I turn stop button. Or maybe something weird with triac. So basically from controller to motor comes five wires. Three steered with triac one neutral and one protection. Can it be something like braking system that does not turn off and then spins rotor in another direction? Please help me :)

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5xhj.jpg

So i found out that on one triac (the one that switches blue cable) there is no voltage drop when i press stop button. This does not happen in case of 2 other triacs that control white and purple cable. The last triac that controls brown does not matter because it is different thing. So this triac that works differently is controlled by optotriac and optotriac is directly controlled by microchip. I think that sth may be wrong with it. All triacs, resistors and optotriacs work fine, i checked them. I just wonder why we have 5 cables to for the single phase motor. One is protection okay. But 3 other ones are the same thing separated by triac so it can be neutral of phase (depends how u put it in the socket) and there is also the last one. I thought that single phase motor is connected by 2 phases and 2 neutral if u want different wire for all windings. U then connect them with capacitor and u're done. Can you help me to understand it?

Comment: We need a schematic diagram. You can add one in using the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' = rotate, 'H' = horizontal flip. 'V' = vertical flip. 

Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: https://m.imgur.com/25uNH69

Comment: There's an image upload button that allows you to embed images in your post rather than in an external link.